# Incompatible Database Name in SharePoint Server Search - Help

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

the windows application event log reports numerous errors for sharepoint

> Event 2583 (SharePoint Server Search) of severity 'Error' occurred 20
>   more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log

although I am not entirely certain what Event 2583 means, it is possibly related to a login failure. however, I cannot pinpoint the problem account or database as sql server logs do not show any login failures.

on the other hand, the sharepoint logs (and maybe it is the uls) shows repeated instances of this error:

> 10/30/2014 12:24:27.79    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2B18)
>     0x0894  SharePoint Server Search        Administration
>     ewf3    High        Incompatible Database Name:
>   Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB_9b22c2e6c1314e2a8f3935d76e5d4b61
>   on server: xxxx , Failure Cause: The database schema version is less
>   than the minimum backwards compatibility schema version that is
>   supported for this component. To resolve this problem upgrade this
>   database. c340c79c-350f-8035-29e6-b8031cab48bd

I am running sharepoint 2013 sp1 as a fresh installation. how could the database schema be out of date? how would I update the database? my server is up to date.

several other processes seem to be failing as a result.

are there any log viewers? not sure they would be an improvement over notepad, but who knows.

sharepoint 2013 sp1, sql server 2012, windows server 2012 r2

Comment: I did find the log viewer at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020

Comment: try to run the PSCOnfig Wizard it will upgrade the database. please share the result.

Comment: i ran the central administration and management shell versions of the configuration wizard with no discernible results.

however, i did give dbo rights to the services and farm accounts, which required a reboot to eliminate the error. while this is a sledge hammer approach, it works. when i have time to study what minimal rights these accounts really need, i will adjust.

the main point is that the error message is misleading. the schema is not out of date; more than likely the programming logic for determining an error is faulty.

Comment: is it fresh installation with no data? or a migrated farm?

Comment: this is a new installation. i explained the resolution concurrent with your response. it had something to do db with rights.

after installing sharepoint using a single account for farm, services, etc., i decided to introduce compartmentalized accounts to improve security. in changing accounts, i may have lost the correct permissions although i am not positive. so far the problem seems resolved even if it was a bit heavy handed.

Comment: Farm Admin accounts required the DBO rights on all Database in the farm, if your installation account is different then farm account then that account also need DBO rights.... Now if You change the Search Services Application account then that account also need DBO rights on all Search DBs.

Comment: thank you - that saved me some time. i have set farm account to dbo membership in the databases. error messages have finally disappeared from uls and event viewer :)

Comment: Awesome, i will add those comments as answer...if you marked it answer other will get benefit and some credit to me....:)

Answer (score 1):

Their are two possible solutions in this situation

1. Run the PSConfig Wizard on the server( either from GUI or command Line)
2. As per your remarks that you change the services accounts, then most probably you have to set the proper DB rights to new account.

> Farm Admin accounts required the DBO rights on all Database in the
>   farm, if your installation account is different then farm account then
>   that account also need DBO rights.... Now if You change the Search
>   Services Application account then that account also need DBO rights on
>   all Search DBs